# How to write to job log from Oracle Report Builder 10.1.2.3.0

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I am touching an old report using Oracle Report Builder 10.1.2.3.0.  I believe I am having trouble with some function within the report, but the error is very generic and does not point to a specific object.

```
    MSG-00002: Init failed
    REP-1416: '': User exit 'G_Catgeory'. .
    REP-0069: Internal error
    REP-57054: In-process job terminated:Terminated with error: 
    REP-1416: MSG-00002: Init failed
    REP-1416: '': User exit 'G_Catgeory'. .
```

Is there a way to write to the concurrent request log file from an RDF (Report Builder data definition)?

I have tried using DBMS_OUTPUT commands within a RDF function but the object will not compile:

```
    'DBMS_OUTPUT is not a procedure or is undefined.'
```

Any tips on how to debug these old school reports is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the author used the `SRW` built-in package and its `USER_EXIT` procedure, i.e.

```
srw.user_exit('G_Catgeory')
```

(by the way, looks like *category* was misspelled. Maybe it should have been `G_Category`).

How to find it? Save the report as a JSP file. Then open it in any text editor (such as Notepad) and search for the above terms. Once you find where it is, you should be able to locate & fix it in Reports Builder.

---

As of the message you'd want to print: use the SRW package (again), but this time the MESSAGE procedure, e.g.

```
srw.message(1, 'This is a message');
```

For more info have a look at Reports Online Help system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on srw.message().  I am able to affect the job log now, which is a huge help (bigly).  I didn't solve the problem yet, but should be well on the way..

Comment: Thanks a 2nd time for this post.  I was stuck trying to find a problem in an RDF that had recently been updated.  Rereading your note about saving as JSP and doing text compare quickly exposed the problem and it is now resolved.